# Show that for the function $f(x) = e^x - x$ the limit of the solution $x_n$ of $f(x) = n$ is $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n = +\infty$.

Tags: limits, functions

I am given the function

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{3cm} f(x) = e^x - x$$

In the first point I had to show that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge 2$ the equation $f(x) = n$ has exactly one solution in the interval $(0, +\infty)$. I showed that without much difficulty.

In the second point I have to show that if $x_n$ is the unique solution of $f(x) = n$ on the interval $(0, +\infty)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge 2$ (so the same "environment" as in that first point), then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = +\infty$.

So I have to find the limit of $x_n \in (0, +\infty)$ where $x_n$ is the unique solution of $f(x_n) = n$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \ge 2$

$$f(x_n) = n$$

$$e^{x_n} - x_n = n$$

But I see no way of isolating $x_n$ such that I could then find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n$.

So how should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to find a lower bound for $x_n$ which also tends to infinity:
$$
 e^{x_n} = x_n + n > n
$$
implies $x_n > \ln n$.